# How is the top link determined in those grouped together "more results from" links?

Tags: seo

Here is a great example of a SERP that has grouped links:

[image]

I am comparing the top link to the bottom 4, and the top link barely has any content and only has a single relevant link on-page. The bottom 4 links seem to match user intent better from what I can tell. None of any of the links have any backlinks, none of them.

All I can see is that the top link was posted long before the bottom 4. Does this mean that in grouped links google simply shows the link that was posted first, regardless of on-page and off-page factors?

If not, please let me know why the top link is outranking the other links.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://www.kickstarterforum.org is not a site you control. You may be able to post to this site, however, you are a user and not the site owner. This site is for those to help manage their own sites. This is no different from your previous question https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114469/how-to-outrank-the-top-link-in-a-group-of-more-results-from-links-using-a-link?noredirect=1#comment151397_114469

Comment: This is a question about SEO and SERP ranking in general.

Comment: Even then, this question is too broad and solicits an opinion. This site is for specific questions that solicit factual answers. In this case, there are too many factors to consider for an answer that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: That is not true. SEO is a complex subject and theories are valid as long as they may work in practice.

Comment: "the top link barely has any content" - The top link is page 1 (of 3) of a 21 post thread that may have seen many visitors and many clicks from the SERPs (given its more mature age)? "None of any of the links have any backlinks, none of them." - Unless you are a webmaster for the site then that is impossible to know. (?) But at the end of the day, those are links that Google has deemed relevant to what has been searched for - so no one really knows.

Comment: Interesting, do you think that google factors in all pages in a thread on online forums, or just the first page?

Comment: As closetnoc indicated above, questions about [websites out of your own control](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top link should be ordered based on relevancy to the search. Older results may rank over the site links beneath the description.

The bottom links under the description then appear to be ordered chronologically by date. I searched for several examples and found them all to be ordered by date. Here are 4 examples of searches that list the dates from new to old (top to bottom). Every search variation returned the same ordering. Notice also that many of these results show an older post as the first link at the top than posts below the description.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]